# How to limit time in mysql for search function

Tags: mysql, limit

I have one problem.

I make search function in php. I need limit searching only for 1 mounth ago.

ex.

I put 'android' word

In result show only titles who containing android openet in last mounth. Oldest no show.

Thank you

EDIT

```
$sql = '
                SELECT aa_search_index.content_id, MATCH(aa_search_index.title, aa_search_index.metadata) AGAINST (?) AS score
                FROM aa_search_index
                LEFT JOIN aa_thread
                    ON (aa_thread.thread_id = aa_search_index.content_id)
                WHERE MATCH(aa_search_index.title, aa_search_index.metadata) AGAINST (?)
                    AND content_type = ?
                    AND content_id != ?

            ';

            $params = array($query, $query, 'thread', $excludedThreadId);
            if (!Search_query::get('options')->showResultsGlobal)
            {
                $params[] = $forum['node_id'];
                $sql .= 'AND aa_thread.node_id = ?
                ';
            }

            $sql .= 'LIMIT 5';


            $results = $this->fetchAllKeyed($sql, 'content_id', $params);

            $threadIds = array_keys($results);
```

Comment: please show your table structure and the query you are working on.

Comment: the table structure please? and `juergen d` has already given the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from your_table
where column_with_text = 'android'
and datetime_column >= curdate() - interval 1 month
```

Comment: Can you make this in ex. above  (in my first post)? I try but not work